# How to get unchecked value in multiselect jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using the multiselect jQuery plugin in my ci app

```
<div class="controls"><select name="delivery_method_' + cloneCntr + '[]" multiple="multiple" class="dm_list_data">' + delivery_method_options + '</select></div>';

$(function () {
    $('.dm_list_data').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        buttonWidth: '170px',
        nonSelectedText: 'Select Delivery Method',
    });
});
```

I have created a function on change. In the function I am not getting unchecked values, it's showing only checked values:

```
$('.dm_list_data').on('change', function() {
    var ischecked= $(this).is(':checked');
    if(!ischecked){
        alert('uncheckd ' + $(this).val());  
    } else {
        alert("checked");
    }
});
```

Comment: use :not jquery selector. http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: i want to get id which is unchecked

Answer (score 1):

On every change setup some attribute to unselected and add them in the array.

```
$('.dm_list_data').on('change', function() {
    var $sel = $(this);
    val = $(this).val();
    $opts = $sel.children();
    prevUnselected = $sel.data('unselected');
    var currUnselected = $opts.not(':selected').map(function() {
        if($("#new-input-"+this.value).length > 0){
            $("#new-input-"+this.value).remove();
        }
        return this.value
    }).get();
    var currSelected = $('.dm_list_data').val();
    $.each(currSelected, function(index, item) {
        if($("#new-input-"+item).length == 0){
            $("#new-options").append("<input type='text' id='new-input-"+item+"' value='"+item+"'>");
        }
    });
});
```

**Updated** as needed

Add one new div `<div id="new-options"></div>`

Comment: based upon checkbox checked i want to add row would you please help me out,if value is checked it should add row if unchecked it should remove row,i will be so glad if you help me out

Comment: on uncheck its not deleting row

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you :**

see the working example : https://jsfiddle.net/3b4dqhfc/5/

*Use jquery's `not` to get the desired result like this*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.dm_list_data').on('change', function() {

   /* use this for unselected value*/
   $('.dm_list_data option').not(':selected').each(function(k,v){
    console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
   });

   /* use this for selected value*/
   $('.dm_list_data :selected').each(function(k,v){
    console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
   });


  }); 
});
```